# Too many if statments?

Tags: apex, batch, dml, merge

So the Apex docs say you have to set the value of the master record if you want to retain the discarded account field values before the `merge` operation.

Is there a better way to do validation for a `merge` DML Operation then having to write tons `if` statements for each field to validate if a field is `null` on a master record before setting it to the retained value of the discarded account?

Example:

```
public void mergeAccountFields(Account masterRecord, Account discardedAccount){

        if(masterRecord.FirstName __c == null){
                masterRecord.FirstName__c = discardedAccount.FirstName__c;
          }

        if(masterRecord.LastName__c == null){
               masterRecord.LastName__c = discardedAccount.LastName__c;
          }

          if(masterRecord.NumberOfLocations__c == null){
                 masterRecord.NumberOfLocations__c = discardedAccount.NumberOfLocations__c;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are just looking for a bit of code refactoring of this, creating a list of the fields you want to copy and then looping over the list and making use of methods like [SObject.get](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2) and [SObject.put](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put_2) is a bit cleaner:

```
private static final SObjectField[] FIELDS = new SObjectField[] {
    Account.FirstName__c,
    Account.LastName__c,
    Account.NumberOfLocations__c,
    ...
};

public void mergeAccountFields(Account masterRecord, Account discardedAccount) {
    for (SObjectField f : FIELDS) {
        if (masterRecord.get(f) == null) {
            masterRecord.put(f, discardedAccount.get(f));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a great place to use a FieldSet also to make this process even more dynamic.